# Does the variance work for values less than 1?

Tags: variance, t-test

I have a two data sets which consist mostly of number between 0 and 1. The standard deviation is 0.1945, which means the variance would be 0.03783. Does this value still work when doing t-tests, even though the variance gets smaller?

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem?  Please give us your context!

Comment: Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: If you're concerned about this, then re-express your numbers as percents.  Now the SD is 19.45% and the variance is 373.3.  (The variance is expressed in percents-squared, of course: and this is the entire point.  It makes no sense to say the variance is "larger" or "smaller" than the SD, because they are in different units.  It's like trying to say that a liter is larger than a tenth of a kilometer.)

Comment: I can't help suspecting there's some concern here that we haven't heard about.